# Justifying $\frac{d A^Tx^TAx}{dx} = 2A^TAx$

Tags: matrices, least-squares

When deriving the normal equations, I have trouble justifying why the derivative of $A^Tx^TAx$ is actually $2A^TAx$.

I know that the derivative of $x^TAx$ wrt $x$ is $2Ax$ when $A$ is symmetric.

Is it correct to say that because $A^TA$ is symmetric, one can simply state that  $\frac{d A^Tx^TAx}{dx} = 2A^TAx$?

Is it that obvious or am I missing something?

Comment: There is something smelly: note that $x^TAx$ is a scalar, and $(Ax)^T=x^TA^T$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I understand, but not sure how to use that information. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Steven01123581321 I think he suspects that $A^{T}x^{T}Ax$ is a typo of $x^{T}A^{T}Ax$. In that case, $A^TA$ is symmetric and we can apply the formula you mentioned directly.

Comment: @Kaira Correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ F = A^T (x^T A x) $

$\nabla F = A^T \nabla (x^T A x) = A^T (A + A^T ) x $